# API Request - Could not load PEM Certificate? OpenSSL Error ,HTTR R, CURL,

Tags: r, curl, get, openssl, httr

I'm trying to make an API request and am passing my SSL cert to the config() parameter of GET. I initially got this working for a few weeks but then had to reinstall R. I did a clean install, deleting all folders, installing R, RTools, RStudio. In this new instance of R the same script no longer works. I've uninstalled/reinstalled HTTR, curl, openssl and no luck still (I've also reinstalled R multiple times).

This is the get request code:

```
conn <- GET(url = "testurl",
               add_headers(header2),
               config(sslcert =  "my_cert.pem", sslkey = "my_key.pem"),
               content_type_json(),
               accept_json())
```

Where `my_cert.pem` and `my_key.pem` were parsed from openssl by:

```
cert <- openssl::read_p12(file = "Data/certificate.pfx", password = "somepassword")

my_cert.pem <- write_pem(cert$cert)

my_key.pem <-  write_pem(cert$key)
```

These are the versions I'm using:
R version: 4.2.2,
RStudio:: 2022.07.2 - 576
rtools42-5355-5357
openssl 2.0.4
curl: 4.3.3
httr: 1.4.4